# Logic behind the review system tallies

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

Let's suppose I'm reading questions on a Stack Exchange site, and assume for argument's sake that I have enough rep for full review queue privs on the site.

If someone posts a new question, and I'm the first to vote it off-topic, by design I do not get credit towards the Close Vote Steward badge.  For example, consider the following screenshot; I was the first to vote to close.

[image: off-topic question]

I tend to be the first to vote on a lot of questions, so technically the current Steward "reviews" count rips me off.  Furthermore, it also could rip off anyone else who hits the close button directly on the question instead of voting to close in the review queue.  Brett Lykins (above) is in the same boat as me.

[image: review queue history]

I have closed far more questions than the 38 Close Vote reviews shown in the review stats above.

[image: close votes]

Regardless of whether or not I voted in the review queue, I still reviewed the question.

**Questions**:

- Why was the current system designed such that we don't count people who click the "close" button directly on the question as reviewers?
- Is this something Stack Exchange is willing to change (for close votes, edit approvals, etc)?

---

Answer (score 6):

In my understanding the point of the review-badges is to motivate users to work through the entries in the queue (as opposed to motivating them to vote to close, reopen, etc). 
It is also valuable that questions that need to be closed do get closed in a timely manner (and alike for others tasks), but this is a slightly different goal.
It is thus natural that only the former gets rewarded in the context of these badges.

This extra incentive can be useful as it can (and did) happen that significant backlogs in  the queues build up and this is one measure against this. 
And to this end, it is a lot more efficient to encourage usage of the queues than, say, votes to close in general (the latter might even be detrimental to that specific goal).
Historically, a likely consideration was also to advertise the then new queues via these then new badges.

There are also some practical ramifications for changing this, including:

- An edit from the close-queue counts as a review. It does not seem reasonable to count every edit (on a question that happens to have a close vote) as a review. Creating another inconsistency if votes to close would count.
- There is already an issue with robo-reviewers. Would each close or reopen vote count as a review this could create problems with user casting spurious votes.

To sum it up: the badges are there to motivate users to look through the queues (as there seems to be need for a little extra motivation), and the details of the implementation reflect this.

Comment: The whole point of the review system is to offload close decisions from moderators.  You either choose "leave open", "close" or "skip".  It's pedantic to claim that you shouldn't get review credit when in fact those that get review credit are also voting to close.  Basically you've told me what I already know... it's been designed that way.  I'm trying to understand the *logic behind the design*.

Comment: There are several difference. One is that one does the the voting to close on the question can happen  on the side while browsing the site normally,  while reviewing is more pure community-service.  Another difference is that, as said, the first reviewer does not review a proposed closure but a question. Also note that making an edit from the close queue counts as a review too. Do you also propose every edit counts as a review (at least in the presence of close-votes)? Anyway, the main point is (as said), the very *reason* for the badge to exist is   to *encourage using the queue.*

Comment: The whole point of my question is there is nothing magic about the review queue.  You don't even need to use the review queue to close the question.  Think about what happened to Brett Lykins vote; he could have gone through the queue, but did not.  Thus he gets no credit because he didn't click the review hyperlink.  That's absurd.

Comment: Again, it is my understanding that the entire point of the badge is to get people to look through the review queue. It is detrimental to that goal to give progress towards it for anything else.

Comment: And perhaps I should add  that the reason for this reason, should be a combination of at one point in  time the review system being new and in need for some promotion, and more importantly there were/are/can be issues with backlogs building up in the queues. So there is a practical need to encourage use of the queues (beyond the goal of getting bad questions closed).

Comment: I restructred my answer in the hope to address more clearly your concerns.